# Camera Target texture not working on some Android devices

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, mobile

I'm building a Unity Android Survival Game and I have an inventory system which among other things displays the player model and the current selected item.

The way this works, I have 2 preview cameras, one attached to the player and the other far off the map. These cameras have their output on 2 different Render Textures and displayed in the inventory on a Raw Image UI element.

The problem is that for some reason IT doesn't work on some Android devices, basically showing black. In the editor, PC build and my phone works just fine. Any ideas what might be the issue?

I've tried different build settings, different camera settings and IT didn't work.

Comment: Until someone else can give you a possible reason, what I'd do is, try to hook RenderDoc to the build running on your phone, through adb. Here's the [documentation](https://renderdoc.org/docs/how/how_android_capture.html). RenderDoc can capture a frame and show you gpu data from it. You can see whether the RenderTexture is properly "painted" or if the RawImage is not displaying it correctly. In general, for graphics bugs, RD is an amazing tool. Also the build needs to be debugable, so I'd wager, make it a dev build. I haven't tried this on Android yet, only Windows and it's very helpful.

Comment: Maybe [this Unity thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/render-texture-showing-black-square-on-android.1248307/) might give you the solution. The thread suggests that it could be an issue with the 32bit depth buffer that's on the RenderTexture.